# Python: Split a String by Number

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I'm reading in text from a PDF and am looking to split a string based on `(anumber)` and keep that value in the split string. So the string:

`Some sentence. (1) Another Sentence. (2) Final Sentence.`

Would turn into

```
Some sentence.
(1) Another Sentence.
(2) Final Sentence.
```

I've tried to do this with `thestring.split('(')` as a workaround, but there are parentheses found in some of the sentences leading to issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split on the regex pattern `\s+(?=\(\d+\))`:

```
inp = "Some sentence. (1) Another Sentence. (2) Final Sentence."
parts = re.split(r'\s+(?=\(\d+\))', inp)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['Some sentence.', '(1) Another Sentence.', '(2) Final Sentence.']
```

The regex pattern used here says to split on one or more whitespace characters which are followed by something like `(1)`, that is, a number contained within parentheses.

Comment: This worked too! Just out of curiosity, what would splitting on `number.` look like. (Number followed by a period). Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Split on `\s+(?=\d+\.)`

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks again for the reply. This didn't seem to work for some reason. Lets say you have `A sentence.1. Another sentence.2. Final Sentence).3. Another sentence.` How would you go about splitting that?

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks again. One last question. So I have numbers that range from 1-50.  `(?=\d+\.)` splits on one digit and a period, and `(?=\d+\d+\.)` splits on two digits. Is there a way to split the string correctly using one `split`? Or will I have to use two?

Comment: My answer already covers splitting on two digits.  Are you saying you want to split on 50 but not 51?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(?<=\.)\s` which means "space preceded by a dot"

```
value = "Some sentence. (1) Another Sentence. (2) Final Sentence."
res = re.split(r"(?<=\.)\s", value)
print(res)  # ['Some sentence.', '(1) Another Sentence.', '(2) Final Sentence.']
```

Comment: This worked! Just out of curiosity, what would splitting on `number.` look like. (Number followed by a period). Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
m = re.search('\([0-9]\).*\.', str)
# regex : escape the parens, capture a ONE DIGIT number from 0-9,
# escape paren, any sequence of characters, end with an escaped dot
# process the match object however you want
```

For all regex forming, I would use [Rubular](https://rubular.com/)